# Ruby: How to split a file into multiple files of a given size

Tags: ruby, file, split, size

I want to split a txt file into multiple files where each file contains no more than 5Mb. I know there are tools for this, but I need this for a project and want to do it in Ruby. Also, I prefer to do this with File.open in block context if possible, but I fail miserably :o(

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'

MAX_BYTES = 5_000_000

file_num = 0
bytes    = 0

File.open("test.txt", 'r') do |data_in|
  File.open("#{file_num}.txt", 'w') do |data_out|
    data_in.each_line do |line|
      data_out.puts line

      bytes += line.length

      if bytes > MAX_BYTES
        bytes = 0
        file_num += 1
        # next file
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This work, but I don't think it is elegant. Also, I still wonder if it can be done with File.open in block context only.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pp'

MAX_BYTES = 5_000_000

file_num = 0
bytes    = 0

File.open("test.txt", 'r') do |data_in|
  data_out = File.open("#{file_num}.txt", 'w')

  data_in.each_line do |line|
    data_out = File.open("#{file_num}.txt", 'w') unless data_out.respond_to? :write
    data_out.puts line

    bytes += line.length

    if bytes > MAX_BYTES
      bytes = 0
      file_num += 1
      data_out.close
    end
  end

  data_out.close if data_out.respond_to? :close
end
```

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your code, like the "mode=" lines in your arguments to File.open. Try reading the ruby docs - they're just a google query away.

Comment: I know there are syntax errors, but "mode" is not one of them. According to ri File.open ->  File.open(filename, mode="r" [, opt])

Comment: Ruby doesn't have named keywords (as in python). The documentation specifies that the default for mode is 'r'. If you don't specify the second attribute to File#open, `mode='r'` is used. In your case, you should just call `File.open("test.txt")` and `File.open("#{file_num}.txt", "w")`

Comment: Note that data_out.puts adds an extra "\n" at the end. You need to chomp your line or do `data_out << line`

Comment: But you are allowed to name your arguments. Thus File.open(file, "r") and File.open(file, mode='r') are equivalents? (And Ruby does not complain and it appears to work just fine).

Comment: Ha, interesting :) This actually seems to work.

Comment: Anyway, what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: I appreciate files opened in block context since that guarantees files are closed correctly (some hidden ensure close). I need to figure out how to close the out file and go to the next one when bytes > MAX_BYTES.

Comment: You could use a `begin .. rescue .. ensure` to make sure that the file is correctly closed.

Comment: The reason you can do "File.open(file, mode = 'r')" is because it will call the "=" method on newly created variable "mode" and return the value that it has been set to, thus resulting in "r" being the argument. It's not considered correct syntax tho.

Also, Wayne Conrad down there left the answer you should accept - unless you're on windows, of course. split is a standard unix tool that you'll have on Linux and Mac OSX. See http://linux.die.net/man/1/split

Comment: @fx_: How could maasha have made the mistake of putting `mode=` into the code *without* reading the ruby docs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[Updated]** Wrote a short version **without any** helper variables and put everything in a method:

```
def chunker f_in, out_pref, chunksize = 1_073_741_824
  File.open(f_in,"r") do |fh_in|
    until fh_in.eof?
      File.open("#{out_pref}_#{"%05d"%(fh_in.pos/chunksize)}.txt","w") do |fh_out|
        fh_out << fh_in.read(chunksize)
      end
    end
  end
end

chunker "inputfile.txt", "output_prefix" (, desired_chunk_size)
```

Instead of a line loop you can use `.read(length)` and do a loop only for the `EOF` marker and the file cursor.

This takes care that the chunky files are never bigger than your desired chunk size.

On the other hand it never takes care for line breaks (`\n`)!

Numbers for chunk files will be generated from integer division of current file curser position by chunksize, formatted with "%05d" which result in 5-digit numbers with leading zero (`00001`).

This is only possible because `.read(chunksize)` is used. In the second example below, it could not be used!

**Update:** *Splitting with line break recognition*

If your really need complete lines with `\n` then use this modified code snippet:

```
def chunker f_in, out_pref, chunksize = 1_073_741_824
  outfilenum = 1
  File.open(f_in,"r") do |fh_in|
    until fh_in.eof?
      File.open("#{out_pref}_#{outfilenum}.txt","w") do |fh_out|
        loop do
          line = fh_in.readline
          fh_out << line
          break if fh_out.size > (chunksize-line.length) || fh_in.eof?
        end
      end
      outfilenum += 1
    end
  end
end
```

I had to introduce a helper variable `line` because I want to ensure that the chunky file size is always **below** the `chunksize` limit! If you don't do this extended check you will get also file sizes above the limit. The `while` statement only successfully checks in next iteration step when the line is already written. (Working with `.ungetc` or other complex calculations will make the code more unreadable and not shorter than this example.)

Unfortunately you have to have a second `EOF` check, because the last chunk iteration will mostly result in a smaller chunk.

Also two helper variables are needed: the `line` is described above, the `outfilenum` is needed, because the resulting file sizes mostly do not match the exact `chunksize`.

Comment: And if your input file contains lines longer than `chunksize` you can modify the `line = fh_in.readline` to `line = fh_in.readline(chunksize)`, but such huge one-line files should be splitted with my first approach instead.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Helper variable `line` can be avoided with the `loop do end` idiom. I can update the second example to use it if you wish

Comment: @Hirurg103 Sure, just do. It's an old answer, but if valuable let's update and make it more idiomatic (as long as it can still be understood).

Answer (score 14):

For files of any size, `split` will be faster than scratch-built Ruby code, even taking the cost of starting a separate executable into account.  It's also code that you don't have to write, debug or maintain:

```
system("split -C 1M -d test.txt ''")
```

The options are:

- `-C 1M` Put lines totalling no more than 1M in each chunk
- `-d` Use decimal suffixes in the output filenames
- `test.txt` The name of the input file
- `''` Use a blank output file prefix

Unless you're on Windows, this is the way to go.

Comment: I remember split. The reason I wanted to do this in Ruby only is that the files I am going to split are of a more particular format. I am pretty convinced that I would be able to extend a generic Ruby only solution to this problem to cover my particular format as well. Unless you can get split to split files at a certain byte size _and_ keeping the line count dividable with 4. I dont see any such options in man split on my Mac. Close but no cigar (I did upvote the answer).

Comment: @maasha, Fair enough.  I admit to a certain amount of "cheek" in giving you the answer you already said you had rejected.  Thanks for the (ill deserved) upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening your outfile inside the infile block, open the file and assign it to variable. When you hit the filesize limit, close the file and open a new one.

Comment: Added such a solution (though a bit ugly) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code actually works, it's simple  and it uses array which make it faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
data = Array.new()
MAX_BYTES = 3500
MAX_LINES = 32
lineNum = 0
file_num = 0
bytes    = 0


filename = 'W:/IN/tangoZ.txt_100.TXT'
r = File.exist?(filename)
puts 'File exists =' + r.to_s + ' ' +  filename
file=File.open(filename,"r")
line_count = file.readlines.size
file_size = File.size(filename).to_f / 1024000
puts 'Total lines=' + line_count.to_s + '   size=' + file_size.to_s + ' Mb'
puts ' '


file = File.open(filename,"r")
#puts '1 File open read ' + filename
file.each{|line|          
     bytes += line.length
     lineNum += 1
     data << line    

        if bytes > MAX_BYTES  then
       # if lineNum > MAX_LINES  then     
              bytes = 0
              file_num += 1
          #puts '_2 File open write ' + file_num.to_s + '  lines ' + lineNum.to_s
             File.open("#{file_num}.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write data.join}
         data.clear
         lineNum = 0
        end



}

## write leftovers
file_num += 1
#puts '__3 File open write FINAL' + file_num.to_s + '  lines ' + lineNum.to_s
File.open("#{file_num}.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write data.join}
```